# Get list of column widths within a range?

Tags: c#, epplus

Using EPPlus, is there a way to determine the widths of columns within a range?

Let's say I want to get the widths of columns 1 through 10 after performing an AutoFit:

```
// autofit columns 1 through 10 based on all data
worksheet.Cells[2, 1, numberOfRows + 2, 10].AutoFitColumns(22, 50);
// determine resulting widths
List<double> columnWidths = worksheet.Cells[2, 1, 2, 10]
    .Select(s=> s.Width/* doesn't work, no Width property */ ).ToList();
```

This does not work, because `.Cells` generates an `IEnumerable<ExcelRangeBase>` and each item in ExcelRangeBase is itself a nested ExcelRangeBase, which seems to go on forever.  So no amount of `.Select` ever reaches a list of cells. The Cells index is crafted to only generate a single row of cells, for which I hoped to get the Width for each one.  Not sure if there is an elegant way to accomplish this.

**How do I populate `columnWidths` with a list of the widths of columns 1 through 10?**

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can reach an `ExcelCellAddress` object for the first cell in a range from from the `.Start` property of an `ExcelRangeBase` object.

Which leads to this alternative approach:

```
List<double> columnWidths = worksheet.Cells[2, 1, 2, 10]
    .Select(s => worksheet.Column(s.Start.Column).Width)
    .ToList();
```

I think its *slightly* better but elegance is firmly in the eye of the beholder! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with for now, but welcome any answers that propose something more elegant:

```
List<double> dataWidths = new List<double>(10);
for(int i= 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    dataWidths.Add( worksheet.Column(i + 1).Width );
}
```